# Not enough disk space to run AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, memory, emulation

When I Run my project in Android Studio, it gives me this [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvvke.png)

I have more than 3GB free RAM and 500MB on my hard disc(C) where this project located.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and I tried answers on SO like wipe data in the AVD manager, and the only thing that worked was, deleting the emulator, and creating a fresh new one.